# OnClickListener in separate class won't work

Tags: java, android

I've tried to use an OnClickListener from a different class but somehow it throws me an error. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class TestClass extends Activity{



    View.OnClickListener l = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }};}
```

Part of the MainActivity:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ...
           btnSpeech = (ImageButton) (findViewById(R.id.microphone));


           obj=new TestClass();
           btnSpeech.setOnClickListener(obj.l);

           ...
```

Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.project/com.example.user.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at com.example.user.project.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: If that stack trace is for that code, then `btnSpeech` is null. Also, `TestClass` and its listener aren't going to work as you expect. You can't instantiate an `Activity` with `new` and have it work correctly. You can, instead, remove `extends Activity`, and replace `getApplicationContext()` with `v.getContext()`. Though, I don't see why you just don't create the listener in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work it gave me again the NullPointerException. I know you could do this easily within the MainActivity but I only wanted to try whether/ how you could start an OnClickListener from a seperate class and I've followed many suggestions from the internet but somehow it didn't work for me.

Comment: If the current stack trace is the same as you posted above, then `btnSpeech` is still null. You've not provided us with enough information to determine why, though.

Comment: Thanks for response but what kind of information do you need, I thought based on the stack trace the main source of the problem has to be the part with btnSpeech and the OnClickListener so I decided to pick only this part because my MainActitvity is quite big to post it as a whole.

Comment: Well, make sure that the `Button` with the ID `microphone` is in the layout that you're using in the `setContentView()` call in `onCreate()`, and that you're calling `setContentView()` before initializing `btnSpeech` with `findViewById()`. If neither of those are the problem, then we'll need to see more code, like the whole `onCreate()` method, and the layout, including its filename.

Answer (score 1):

You get a NullPointerException because your `btnSpeech` is null. `findViewById()` returns null if you use a wrong id for the view, maybe this is the problem.
What is sure is that your exception has nothing to do with the OnClickListener. If you read your stacktrace carefully you see that it says that `setOnClickListener()` was called on a object that was null.

And, as Mike commented, you cannot instantiate activities with the `new` keyword. Use `startActivity()` with an intent or make `TestClass` not extend `Activity`.

Comment: thanks. but I have checked the id of the button in XML it is definitely the correct id.Could it be somtehing else instead of findViewById()?

Comment: @Andr There are many cases in which `findViewById()` returns null. I can't guess what's the problem in your case with so little code. Did you call `setContentView()` at the beginning of `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 1):

this is what you have just done quickly, but not if this will solve your problem

```
public class TestClass {

    public static Context context;

    public static View.OnClickListener getListener(){
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
    }
```

}

In Activity

```
 TestClass.context = this;
 my_button.setOnClickListener(TestClass.getListener());
```

Hope this help..

Comment: Thanks but it gave me the same error with NullPointerException :-(

Comment: If your Id from yor button is the same in layout, tries to clean the project, if is android studio, press in menu **build** and then **Clean Project**, after that, please tell me if is the same mistake that you published, sorry for my bad english